# Print all files content under all subdirectories in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have a shell script code I made with the purpose of printing all the content of files under all subdirectories from the subdirectory I am at.Though I am getting some errors..

I ran the shell script with the command:./thisCodeScriptFile

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *; do
   if [ -d $i ]; then
      cd $i
      ~/thisCodeScriptFile
      cd ..
   else
      cat $i >> ~/resultFile
   fi
done
```

The errors I received :

```
cat: '*': No such file or directory
cat: '*': No such file or directory
cat: '*': No such file or directory
cat: '*': No such file or directory
cat: '*': No such file or directory
cat: '*': No such file or directory
cat: resultFile: input file is output file
cat: '*': No such file or directory
cat: '*': No such file or directory
cat: '*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Don't use this script in your home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cat: '*': No such file or directory` error is due to the folder being empty. I assume the other error is because you kicked off the script in your home folder. I suggest you modify your script to test for empty folders as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *; do
   if [ -d $i ]; then
      cd $i
      if [ ! -z "$(ls -A .)" ]; then
          ~/thisCodeScriptFile
      fi
      cd ..
   else
echo $i
      cat $i >> ~/resultFile
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use this if you want. simple yet effective

```
 find . -type f -printf '%f\r\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, though I need the files content.This list contains directories as well so cat command will have a problem with "receiving" it and print the files content